# Android: How to use selector with a single item

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-selector, android-togglebutton

I have a ToggleButton with text and I want to show a drawableStart next to it only if it's selected. When it isn't selected, I'd like to show just the text (the drawable should disappear).

I tried setting up my selector with just a single item for when `android:state_checked=true` but when I run the app it gets completely ignored. How can I do this?

Here's my code ToggleButton code:

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/list_item_service_list_add_button"
            style="@style/OrangeToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textOff="@string/list_item_service_list_add"
            android:textOn="@string/list_item_service_list_added"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/add_to_cart_icon_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

and here's my `add_to_cart_icon_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_circle"
        android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: can you try with `@null` for drawable? I mean use both states but for false use `@null` instead of a drawable name.

Comment: @abdullahzkhan do you mean like `<item android:drawable="@null" android:state_checked="false" />`? I tried that and it gave me an InflateException.

Comment: I guess you would have to use a transparent drawable then

Comment: i tried and its still not working.